# IOS Swift3 card stack overlay

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using swift3 with Xcode8 to develop an iPhone app. I want to achieve the following effect: There are a set of cards and I can scroll and tap a card to select the card, then the selected card will be will be displayed by itself.

I am quite new in IOS development, what I am thinking is using the collection view, but how to achieve this kind of card overlay effect with collection view?

Or should I use something else? Can anyone give some clue? Thanks!

[image: sample image]

Comment: There are some libs you can try: [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) or [CardStack](https://github.com/hyperoslo/CardStack) or [TGLStackedViewController](https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I saw these libraries but all in OC language, is there any in swift? Or if I am not using libraries, any clue for implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MMCardView](https://github.com/MillmanY/MMCardView), currently supporting Swift 3.

In terms of implementing this, a collection view would be a start - looking deeper into libraries this is the common way of implementation. If you don't want to implement a library, take a look at the libraries files and see how they were implemented and adapt it to the way that you want.

Comment: Thank you for the information, this library is quite suitable for me!